# Can the operator "(" be overloaded?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know that the operator "()" can be overloaded however I was curious about the operator "(" alone it seems that this cannot be overloaded. I Tried looking for online for a reason but I still cant find one. The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421715#4421715) doesnt say anything about the "(" operator alone.I know the no one would use the "(" operator alone but I am asking this question out of curiosity. Thanks.

Comment: There is no operator (, nor is there an operator [.

Comment: What kind of call are you envisioning with that operator?

Comment: @djf not really any call i just wanted to know why "(" alone cannot be overloaded.But the answers help clear this out that "(" is not an operator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(` is not an operator, so no, it can't be overloaded.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Will mark this as an answer once the timer is up